# Apache nutch fetching but not saving file content

Tags: cassandra, nutch

I asked nutch to crawl a local file: http://localhost:8080/a.txt. I am running the HTTP server and I can see nutch trying to access the file (and before it, /robots.txt). I am using cassandra as backend.

However, I cannot see any data from the crawl. When I do
./bin/nutch readdb -dump data ..., I get the following output.

Can someone help me with a sane answer to this question? Where is the webpage data?

$ cat data/part-r-00000
http://localhost:8000/a.html    key:    localhost:http:8000/a.html
baseUrl:    null
status: 2 (status_fetched)
fetchTime:  1426811920382
prevFetchTime:  1424219908314
fetchInterval:  2592000
retriesSinceFetch:  0
modifiedTime:   0
prevModifiedTime:   0
protocolStatus: (null)
parseStatus:    (null)